# Errors when compiling Maven

Tags: java, html, actionscript-3, maven, plugins

I am trying to use Jangaroo to convert FLEX to HTML 5 and JavaScript. In order to do so I need to use Maven, and when compiling Maven (mvn compile), I get a couple errors. The errors are displayed below. Can anoyone help me out???

---

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/jangaroo/jangaroo-maven-plu
gin/0.8.3/jangaroo-maven-plugin-0.8.3.pom
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project net.jangaroo.examples:hello-world:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT (F:\PROJE
CT_HOME\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin net.jangaroo:jangaroo-maven-pl
ugin:0.8.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read arti
fact descriptor for net.jangaroo:jangaroo-maven-plugin:jar:0.8.3: Could not tran
sfer artifact net.jangaroo:jangaroo-maven-plugin:pom:0.8.3 from/to central (http
://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:80 [repo.mave
n.apache.org/199.27.74.192, repo.maven.apache.org/199.27.74.129] failed: Connect
ion timed out: connect -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildin
gException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResoluti
onException
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Maven tries to download everything it needs for your build from its central Maven repository (or any other repository you specify in your Maven settings or `pom.xml`).
The error "Connection timed out" means that `repo.maven.apache.org` is (currently) not reachable from your machine under IP address 199.27.74.129. Either you have a network (configuration) problem, or the server was really down when you tried to compile.
What is the output when you execute the following command?

```
ping repo.maven.apache.org
```

After you have compiled your project once, it can be re-compiled offline using the Maven command line switch `-o` (unless you add new dependencies that need to be downloaded).

Btw., you should really update to a more recent Jangaroo version. As of now, this would be 1.0.2 for `jangaroo-maven-plugin` and `jangaroo-runtime` and 1.0.3 for all other `jangaroo-libs` (`jangaroo-browser`, `jooflash`, etc.).

Comment: C:\PROJECT_HOME>ping repo.maven.apache.org

Pinging prod.fastly.net [23.235.44.129] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 23.235.44.129:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
- Also, I have yet to successfully compile it because of those errors. I used the pom.xml code that the Jangaroo supplied, their sample jangaroo source code, and made the folders and directories as displayed in the tutorial. https://github.com/CoreMedia/jangaroo-tools/wiki/Tutorial-~-Project-Directory-Structure